# The set is meager if it has a cover of clopen meager sets

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, transfinite-recursion

Let $X$ be a topological space such that there exists a collection of meager clopen sets $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} C_i$. I want to prove that $X$ is then meager itself.

As each $C_i$ is meager there is a sequence of nowhere dense sets $(N_{i,n})^\infty_{n=1}$ such that $C_i = \bigcup^\infty_{n=1} N_{i,n}$. For natural $n$ define set  $M_n = \bigcup_{i\in I} N_{i,n}$. Then by basic set theory

$$
X = \bigcup_{i \in I} C_i = \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty N_{i,n} = 
 \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i \in I} N_{i,n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty  M_n.
$$

So, we need to show that each $M_n$ is meager and we are done. Initaly I thought that it may be possible to use clopennes to write something like

$$
\mathrm{int}\;\mathrm{cl}\;M_n = \mathrm{int}\;\mathrm{cl}\;\bigcup_{i \in I} N_{i,n} =
\bigcup_{i \in I} \mathrm{int}\;\mathrm{cl}\; N_{i,n} = \bigcup_{i \in I} \emptyset =\emptyset,
$$
where $\mathrm{int}$ and $\mathrm{cl}$ stand for interior and closure operations respectively, so $M_n$ is nowhere dense. But this works only if $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ are disjoint. This won't work in general, for example take $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ to be a collection of all clopen sets in $X=\mathbb{Q}$, and choose $N_{i,n}$ to be a collection of singletons so each $M_n = \mathbb{Q}$. I know that in this example sets $X$ is meager, but I wanted to show that argument above may fail in general.

My first idea was to transform $(C_i)_{i\in I}$ into a different disjoint clopen cover $(C'_j)_{j \in J}$, such that for each $j\in J$ there is $i\in I$ with $C'_j\subset C_i$. But how to do so? In case $X$ is locally connected one can just take its connected components, but this won't work in general. I thought that a transfinite induction may also work. By abuse of notation assume that $I$ is an ordinal, let $\mathcal{C}_{1}$ be an well-order by $I$ version of $(C_i)_{i\in I}$. then for a non-limit ordinal $\kappa + 1$ we may construct a Set $\mathcal{C}_{\kappa + 1} = \{ C^\kappa_{1}, \ldots, C^\kappa_\kappa \} \cup \{ C^\kappa_{\kappa +1} \setminus C^\kappa_\kappa , \ldots,  C^\kappa_{I} \setminus C^\kappa_\kappa   \}$, which is an ordered set of clopen sets, where each set in the first brackets is disjoint from any other set in $\mathcal{C}_{\kappa + 1}$. And for the limit ordinals $\lambda$ just write $\mathcal{C}_\lambda = \{ C^i_i | i < \lambda\} \cup \left\{ \bigcap_{i < \lambda} C^i_j |\lambda \le j \le I \right\}$? I don't think this will work, as clopeness may be lost. But in the end I hoped $\mathcal{C}_I$ to be a disjoint cover I seek.

Please, help me to prove this statement.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? Is this an exercise? Are you sure it's true?

Comment: This is a problem 9.124 from A. Wilansky's Topology for analysis, I want to prove it because it used for proving Baire-related facts for topological groups later on.

Comment: @tomasz problem 9.3.124 to be exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the trick.  Let $(U_j)_{j\in J}$ be a maximal family of disjoint meager open subsets of $X$ (such a maximal family clearly exists by Zorn's lemma, for instance).  Let $U=\bigcup U_j$.  Then $U$ is meager using the line of argument you propose, since the $U_j$ are disjoint.  But now observe that $X\setminus U$ is closed and has empty interior (if a point $x$ was in its interior, then we could find a meager open neighborhood of $x$ contained in it which we could then add to our family, contradicting maximality).  So we can add $X\setminus U$ as one more nowhere dense set to witness that $X$ is meager.

(Incidentally, this argument only requires the $C_i$ to be open, not necessarily clopen.  So this shows that if a topological space is *locally* meager (i.e., each point has a meager neighborhood) then it is meager.)

Comment: I'm afraid if $U_j$ are not clopen then $U$ may not be a meager as my argument may fail. But if we demand from $U_j$ to be clopen, then the maximality argument may fail.

Comment: Well you did not give the details of your argument so I am not sure what step you think fails.  But it is true that if you have nowhere dense sets $N_j$ that are contained in disjoint open subsets $U_j$ then the union $\bigcup N_j$ is still nowhere dense.

Comment: If you were claiming that you can just say $\operatorname{int cl}\bigcup N_i=\bigcup \operatorname{int cl}N_i$ whenever the $N_i$ are contained in disjoint clopen sets, then that does not work (even with clopen rather than open sets).  For instance the $N_i$ themselves could be disjoint clopen sets whose union is dense in the whole space (but not equal to the whole space), and then the interior of the closure of the union is the whole space.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/109241/91850 lets have this as a reference.

Comment: It is not true that $\{\star\} \times [0,1] \subset \mathrm{int}\;\mathrm{cl}\;\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i$ in your example.  An open neighborhood of $\{\star\} \times [0,1]$ would need to contain an entire vertical interval around $(i,0)$ for each $i\in[0,1]$.

Comment: The argument I had in mind for $\bigcup N_i$ being nowhere dense is that if its closure had nonempty interior, the interior would have to intersect some $U_j$.  But since $U_j$ is open, $U_j\cap \operatorname{cl}\bigcup N_i=\bigcup \operatorname{cl}(U_j\cap N_i)=\operatorname{cl}(U_j\cap N_j)$ which has empty interior since $N_j$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Looking at the reference you posted I guess this is basically the same as Hamkins's argument for his Claim.

Comment: I think overall you are correct, and you answer is surely correct accepting Banach category theorem. My only point was that $U_j$ and $\mathrm{cl}\;N_i$ may have nonempty  intersection even for $i\neq j$ if $U_j$ is not closed.

Comment: That's not possible though if $U_j$ is open.  For $i\neq j$, since $X\setminus U_j$ is a closed set containing $N_i$, it contains the closure of $N_i$.